# Schedule script to update database with external data

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, scheduler

I have developed a website that retrieves beers informations from a website called ratebeer.com to display and stock them on my side.

To obtain the score given to one of these beers, ratebeer.com has developed a script I had to copy/paste in my code and to which I just have to provide the beer number (the reference of the product).

Ex: http://www.ratebeer.com/beer/westvleteren-12-xii/4934/ is one of these products I want to get the score (i.e. 100/100). The product reference of the beer is hereby 4934.

The script I use dynamically in an ASP.net formview is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" style="color: yellow !important" src="http://www.ratebeer.com/javascript/sc.asp?b=<%#: Item.RateBeerNumber  %>"></script>
```

The score will be instantely fetched and showed to the user as soon as he consults my webpage. This is working really well so far but I would like to do something more:

My goal is to retrieve all the scores for all the beers I have in my database on a daily basis and to record them in the database.

The first issue I encounter is that I cannot affect the returned value of the script to a c# variable in order to pass the value to a stored procedure or anything to update my database.

The second issue is that I do not know how to run a script on a daily basis to fetch the various scores.

Regards!

Comment: Your goal is not clear, do you want to retrieve scores through the script (while the user is opening the web page) and then you upload it and store it in your database?

Comment: While the user is opening the web pages I already can do that. It's just that I can't record the score in the database.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cron jobs in linux to run a script in a particular interval or if you are using windows machine you can use shedule jobs.

Comment: Ok I have found some code on the web about schedulers but I still dont get how to affect the value retrieved by the script to a c# variable.

Comment: For those who want to know I use as a scheduler [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) which is very easy to implement and very well documented.